# Postrgesql : Edit a specific field from a nested array field of a jsonb value

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

The table:

```sql
table Bar(
  id int,
  my_json jsonb
)
```

Example of what `my_json` looks like:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "columns": [
    {
      "type": "integer",
      "field": "myField",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "integer",
          "field": "myField"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "integer",
      "field": "otherField",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "integer",
          "field": "myField"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "integer",
      "field": "baz",
      "children": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to change all the `"type": "integer"` to `"type": "string"` where the matching `"field"` equals to `"myField"`.

I made the lvl 1 (at `columns` lvl) with this next sql query:

```sql
with query as (
    select ('{columns,' || index - 1 || ',type}')::text[] as path,
           b.id
    from Bar b,
         jsonb_array_elements(my_json -> 'columns') with ordinality arr(col, index)
    where col ->> 'field' = 'myField'
      and col ->> 'type' = 'integer'
)
update Bar b
set my_json = jsonb_set(b.my_json, query.path, '"string"', false)
from query
where b.id = query.id;
```

I have to achieve the lvl 2 (ideally understand any lvl) with the nested array `children` which may be null, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: have you looked at a regex replace solution? it might be the best or might not work at all but it's worth checking

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited, I hope it makes it easier.

Comment: @Kendle The fields can be at any position in the array, and there's a lot of other fields, which makes it hard to parse with a regex. I must confess I didn't try it, but I might give it a try if I definitely can't do it by the jsonb way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it! Here's the solution I found:

```sql
with non_null_children as (
    select index - 1 as idx,
           col,
           b.id as bar_id
    from Bar b,
         jsonb_array_elements(my_json -> 'columns') with ordinality arr(col, index)
    where col ->> 'children' is not null
), query as (
    select ('{columns,' || nnc.idx || ',children,' || index - 1 || ',type}')::text[] as path,
           b.id
    from Bar b,
         non_null_children nnc,
         jsonb_array_elements(nnc.col -> 'children') with ordinality arr(col2, index)
    where b.id = nnc.bar_id
      and col2 ->> 'field' = 'myField'
      and col2 ->> 'type' = 'integer'
)
update Bar b
set my_json = jsonb_set(b.my_json, query.path, '"string"', false)
from query
where b.id = query.id;
```

Explanation:

- I list all the items which contain children, each combined with its `columns` index and its Bar id -> `non_null_children`
- For each Bar id / column index, I can work on the matching field operation, just like the lvl 1.

I don't know if this is the most optimized solution, feel free to improve it if you think it's necessary.